# Replace under warranty Bradford White or get a new Rheem water heater?

Tags: plumbing, water-heater

I have a Bradford White water heater that is about 4 years old, still under warranty, and has started leaking.  My understanding is that it must be replaced.

The plumber I contacted about this told me that Bradford White water heaters are known to fail very frequently usually just after the warranty expires.

He suggested that rather than replace the Bradford White, I have him install a Rheem.

He quoted me roughly $1250 to install a new Rheem, or about $800 to  install a replacement Bradford White.

Do you think spending the extra $450 is a good idea?

Comment: Per the [faq](http://diy.stackexchange.com/faq) questions about brands and costs are considered off topic because they are subjective and localized.

Answer (score 1):

Talk to a different plumber. I don't trust anyone who suggests that I replace something that I could get for free under warranty! Even if it's not a good make you'll still get a new one and get another 4-5 years out of it, then you'll be free to buy the latest and greatest which will be more efficient. I'd get someone else to install a warranty replacement and save that money up.